# what's wrong with this integral by parts calculation?

Tags: integration

Today, I just finda confusing quesiton. If I do this way:

$$\int { \frac { dx }{ x }  } =x\left( \frac { 1 }{ x }  \right) -\int { xd } \left( \frac { 1 }{ x }  \right) =1+\int { \frac { dx }{ x }  } $$

then, $0=1$

what's wrong with this calculation? in another words, why I cannot apply "integral by parts" method to this simple $\dfrac { 1 }{ x }$?

Thanks.

According to $\int{u}dv=uv-\int{v}du$, here I just want my $dv$ be $dx$. then the $u$ is$\dfrac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Two valid integration methods can produce antiderivatives that differ by a non-zero constant. Don't forget about the $+{}C$.  (There is currently a minus sign error/typo.)

Comment: Watch your sign. That minus should be a plus. With that correction, everything is correct.

Comment: thanks. I corrected it. it's a "+". But with this correction, something is still wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First off, $$\int \frac{1}{x}\,dx = \ln x +C$$

Second, using integration by parts,
if you let $u = 1$, and $dv = \frac{1}{x}$, then
$$uv-\int v\,du = \ln x - \int 0\,du =\ln x - K  = \ln x +C$$
if I let $C = -K$.

If you let $u = \frac{1}{x}$, and $dv = 1$, then
$$uv-\int v\,du = \frac{1}{x}\cdot x - \int x\cdot \frac{-1}{x^2}\,dx = 1+\int\frac{1}{x}\,dx = 1+\ln x+K = \ln x + C$$
if I let $C = 1+K$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you conclude that

$$
\int x \, d \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \int \frac{dx}{x}
$$

You can let $u = \frac{1}{x}$, and then

\begin{align}
\int x \, d \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
    & = \int \frac{du}{u} \\
    & = \ln u \\
    & = -\ln x
\end{align}

And now your LHS and RHS only differ by a constant, which as André Nicolas points out, is perfectly normal in integration.

Comment: Because $d\frac { 1 }{ x } =-\frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 } } dx$, then $\int { xd\left( \frac { 1 }{ x }  \right)  } =-\int { \frac { dx }{ x }  } $. Sorry I forgot a "-". And I have corrected it.

Comment: Either way is fine.  Anyway, your problem is mostly the sign.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  \int_{a}^{b} \frac{dx}{x}
  &=
  \left[\frac{1}{x} \cdot x \right]_{a}^{b}-
  \int_{a}^{b} x\, d\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \\
  &=
  (1-1)+\int_{a}^{b} \frac{dx}{x} \\
  &=
  \int_{a}^{b} \frac{dx}{x}
\end{align*}